# How to handle permission issue in below Marshmallow Android

Tags: android

How can be handle permission issue in Sdk 22 .If user manually deny the permission.Their is way of handling permission in Marshmallow,but how can be it done in below M?.

Comment: The user cannot revoke permissions on Android 5.1 and lower.

Comment: which type of issue occur in your app

Answer (score 1):

Before Android Marshmallow users accept permissions just by installing your app (They can see the request permission list before installing).

So you don't need to handle denied permission for users running a version below Android Marshmallow.

Answer (score 1):

for below Marshmallow version just give permission in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Android minimum sdk version 21-22 i.e. 5.0 doesn't need to check permission but when we have to Test the our app on different phones for eg. on minimum sdk version 23 i.e. on Marshmallow. You need to check permission externally in your App.

For Handling the permissions in App

**Write below code in Your Starting_Activity**

```
private void requestingPermission(){
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)){
    //Exaplian here why you need this permission
}
//Ask for the permission
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{ 
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, },STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);}
```

Now Add another

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

//checking the request code of Permission request
if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE){
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){//Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Permission Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Dont forget call below method in your activity onCreate() Method

```
requestingPermission();
```